# Declaration of GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Session::run() must be compatible with

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp, graphaware

I'm following the tutorial [provided by graphaware](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client), and I keep getting the following error while just trying to perform the basic usage tutorial:

> Fatal error: Declaration of GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Session::run() must be compatible with GraphAware\Common\Driver\SessionInterface::run($statement, array $parameters = Array, $tag = NULL) in **C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\vendor\graphaware\neo4j-php-client\src\HttpDriver\Session.php** on **line 24**

This is the code I'm executing:

```
<?php

require_once 'C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\vendor\autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
->addConnection('default', 'http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474') // Changed the login info back to default
->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:7687') // Changed the login info back to default
->build();

$result = $client->run("MATCH (n:User) RETURN n");

?>
```

I've tried removing and readding the Neo4J PHP client multiple times, but this does not fix it

I'm using Neo4J v3.0.6 and have had this same problem for days. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT: composer.json**

```
{
"require": {
    "everyman/neo4jphp": "dev-master",
    "graphaware/neo4j-php-client": "4.0"
}
}
```

Comment: It seems it tries to require a wrong version. do you have the `bcmath` and `mbstring` extensions installed ? How did you required the package ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen `extension_loaded` function says both bcmath and mbstring are installed and loaded. I `require`d the package from the path `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\vendor\autoload.php` as listed from above. Also I'm on Windows. Hope that helps.

Comment: I mean how did you installed it with composer ? Try to rm -rf vendor and rm composer.lock and do a composer install again

Comment: [This was the result after performing the commands you said](https://i.imgur.com/Hyn942j.png). Still getting the same error from before.

Comment: Can you post your composer.json ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Done

Comment: This is the composer.json of the neo4j-php-client, you shouldn't use this one ! You should create your own

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was the one you were referring to. I have replaced it with the one from my `ComposerSetup\bin` path now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. The problem was an outdated version of the `neo4j-php-client (version 4.0.0)`. Here's what I did:

1. Delete the `vendor/` folder and `composer.lock` file from your source folder.
2. Add a [caret](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret) in front of the version number in your `composer.json`:

   ```
   "graphaware/neo4j-php-client": "^4.0"
   ```
3. Then do a `composer install` in the source folder through the terminal.

It installed the latest version `graphaware/neo4j-php-client (4.6.4)` and solved the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and "solved" it but with a suboptimal solution:

Directly (!) in GraphAware\Common\Driver\SessionInterface, I tried to replace

```
public function run($statement, array $parameters = Array, $tag = NULL);
```

by

```
public function run($statement, $parameters = array(), $tag = null);
```

which seems to be what is expected by Graphaware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Session

And it works... for now (until package update?)

Could that be a bug?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this as well, interchanging both functions from `Session.php` and `SessionInterface.php` to match each other, but it gave me another error regarding an unresolved host. I'm contemplating just using a different library/solution altogether at this point.